# Add shard replica in SolrCloud

Tags: solr, lucene, sharding, solrcloud

Everytime i start a new node in the Solr cluster a shard or a shard replica is assigned automatically.
How could i specify which shard/shards should be replicated on this new node ?

I'm trying to get to a configuration with 3 shards, 6 servers - one for each shard master and 3 for the replicas - and shard1 to have 3 replicas, one on each of the servers while shard1 and shard2 only one.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the core admin at the solrcloud Web GUI, unload the core that has been automatically assigned to that node and then create a new core, specifying the collection and the shard you want it to be assigned at. After you create that core you should see at the cloud view , that your node has been adeed to that specific shard and after some time that all documents of that shard have been sychronized with your node.